# Does the following code sequence make sense in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I haven't used async/await very often and I'm not fully comfortable with them. I am trying to make an operation that is synchronous to be run asynchronously. Can you tell me if the following code snippet makes sense:

```
public static async Task<string> FileVersionAsync(string localFilePath)
{
    FileVersionInfo versionInfo;
    try
    {
        versionInfo = await Task.FromResult(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(localFilePath));
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        return "File Version Checker does not have permission to read file version";
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return "Unable to find configured file";
    }
    if (versionInfo.FileVersion == null)
        return "N/A";

    return versionInfo.FileVersion;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do.  The code you wrote will work with async / await, but it will not be executed asynchronously.   I t will block on FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo().  If you want the code to really execute asynchronously, replace Task.FromResult with Task.Run.

Comment: @Nick that wouldn't make it _asynchrounous_. It would execute synchronously, but _paralllel_ on another thread (which might be what OP wants).

Comment: Preferably you'd want to use an async version of `GetVersionInfo` if one exists.

Comment: its bad that you return a string in all cases.

Comment: The code compiles @LarsTech.

Comment: There is no async version of GetVersionInfo - my goal is that if that file is blocked by another process and can't be read - I don't want the caller to remain stuck.

Comment: @RenéVogt, if the original method has no asynchronous version (either via async or IAsyncResult), there is no possible way to make it asynchronous.  You can only run it in parallel.  This is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it does not make sense.**

The only reason to make your function async is if somewhere inside it awaits other functions that are async. In fact your compiler warns you if you forget to await somewhere.

The async-await syntax was invented as a replacement for other task functions like Task.ContinueWith, Task.FromResult, Task.FromException etc.

[In this interview Eric Lippert compared async-await with a cook who has to prepare breakfast](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) Search somewhere in the middle for async-await.

If a cook has to prepare breakfase he starts to boil water. But instead of waiting for the water to cook, he starts slicing bread, and do other things. Only after he has nothing to do anymore he starts waiting idly for the water to boil after which he makes the tea.

Similarly: if a program has to wait for an external process to perform a request, like a database query, write data to a file, get information from the internet etc. async-await makes sure that your thread doesn't wait idly. Instead your thread goes up its call stack to see if one of the callers can continue working without the result from the other process.

You'll see this in the following code:

```
public async Task<string> ReadTextFile()
{
    StreamReader txtReader = File.OpenText(...);
    // read the complete text file; don't wait until finished yet
    Task<String> taskTxt = txtReader.ReadToEndAsync();

     // as we didn't use await, we can continue processing:
     DoSomething();

     // now we need the result from the read action: await for it
     // the result of await Task<TResult> is the TResult:
     string importedTxt = await taskTxt;
     return importedTxt;
}
```

Some guidelines for async-await:

- Only use async-await if you call at least one other async function
- instead of `void` return `Task`, instead of `TResult` return `Task<TResult>`
- Only exception: the async event handler: this async function returns void
- The return of `await Task` is `void`; the return of `await Task<TResult>` is `TResult`
- If you don't need the result of an async function right now, and if you can do something meaningful while the task is processing: start the task by calling the async function, but don't await for it. Only await when you need the result

.

```
public async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // indicate you will do something time consuming:
     this.ProgressBar1.Visible = true;

     await DoSomethingTimeconsumingAsync(...);

     // finished:
     this.progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

This will make sure that whenever your thread has to wait something, it can do other things, and thus your GUI remains responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `Task`, `await` and `async` do not make something asynchronous; they merely provide the *plumbing* to work with asynchronous code *when it happens*. In your example: it never happens asynchronously, so all you are doing is adding plumbing overhead for no benefit.

The compiler will generate a *ton* of extra code that will turn out to never be hit, because when it gets to the `await` it'll discover that the task is already complete, and will simply continue on the existing thread.

To actually be asynchronous, you need ... something that is async. This could be external IO, or could be something threading related - but note that simply jumping to another thread *doesn't buy you anything*: it just adds a context switch.

If there was a `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfoAsync` method, what you are doing might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

No. There appears to be absolutely no need to make this method async, because Task.FromResult is ready immediately.

Comment: `Task.FromResult` is not "ready" _immediatly_. It _blocks_ until `GetVersionInfo` returns. And then, yes, the `Task` is already completed.

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by ready immediately - I meant that it returns as soon as it's called (which is a reasonable definition of immediately). Of course, it is only called after GetVersionInfo returns.

Comment: agree with that, the wording in the answer just sounds a little unclear in that point.